# Download file from a request made to another server without saving it on the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, microservices, multer

I am making a request to another server to download a zip file, what I do now is make a request post to another server which responds with a zip file, I save it on the server I am on and send it with res .download,
what I would like is to be able to download that zip without having to save it in the local storage

```
const form = new FormData();
    form.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    form.append("instancia", req.file.buffer, req.file.originalname);
    form.append("parametros", "XYZ);


    const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/archivos", form, {
        headers: {
            ...form.getHeaders(),
        },
        responseType: "stream",
    });
    
    let headerLine = response.data.headers["content-disposition"];
    let startFileNameIndex = headerLine.indexOf('"') + 1;
    let endFileNameIndex = headerLine.lastIndexOf('"');
    let filename = headerLine.substring(startFileNameIndex, endFileNameIndex);
      
    response.data.pipe(FS.createWriteStream(__dirname + "/" + filename).on('close',function(){
        res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', filename);
        res.download(__dirname + "/" + filename);
        
      }))
```

is this really possible?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but you can certainly pipe one stream into another where bits that arrive are immediately sent out and never stored locally (other than small pieces stored momentarily in memory).

Comment: Do you know where I can see how to do that? I'm new to this :(

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe one stream into another where bits that arrive are immediately sent off into another stream without accumulating the whole file in local storage.  Here's an example of a GET request in Express that fetches content from an external server and pipes that back to an Express response and formats it as an attachment that the browser will promise the user to download.  You can obviously set the content-xxx headers however you want it.  Here I've configured it so the browser will prompt the user to save the file.

```
const express = require('express');
const https = require('https');
const app = express();

app.get("/file", (req, res) => {
    const request = https.get("https://www.google.com", readable => {
        const contentType = readable.headers['content-type'];
        res.set({
            'Content-Type': contentType,
            'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="google.html"',
        });
        readable.pipe(res);
    }).on('error', e => {
        console.log(e);
        if (res.headersSent) {
            // if headers already sent, not much we can do on an error,
            // but just end the connection
            res.end();
        } else {
            res.sendStatus(500);
        }
    });
});

app.listen(80);
```

You can run this, make a request to `/file` and see that the browser prompts you to save a file, save that file, then open the file in an editor and see that the data is the HTML page from google.com.